# What is the word for "gains made due to experience"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What is the right phrase (or word) to describe "gains made when a person or organization repeatedly performs an act or operation"?

Economies of scale will arise due to increase in production. This will result in reduction of costs--but what are the benefits of *experience*?

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence where you intend to use the word?

Comment: We use the term *learning curve* to get the idea across. I don't know of a term that specifically refers to the marginal advantage experience affords.

Comment: "Good judgement comes from experience, and a lot of that comes from bad judgement." ~ *The Mechanic* (Arthur Bishop)

Comment: Well, in philosophical terms,  I would call it "wisdom". As per Merriam Webster dictionary, the definition of wisdom is

   
    " accumulated philosophic or scientific learning :  knowledge"

Comment: What you're asking for sounds very much like what your term *experience* evokes. E.g.: Q1 - How did you know which path to take through the jungle? A1 - Experience. Q2 - How did you know to look out for bears? A2 - Experience. Q3 - Can you be more specific? A3 - Bitter experience.

Answer (score 1):

***Practise makes perfect***.  From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Practice+makes+perfect):

> Frequently doing something makes one better at doing it, as in I've
>   knit at least a hundred sweaters, but in my case practice hasn't made
>   perfect. This proverbial expression was once put as Use makes mastery,
>   but by 1560 the present form had become established.

This expression is best applied to a person, not an organization.  For a person, *practice makes perfect* is appropriate for both physical and mental tasks, from tennis to doing crossword puzzles, to speaking a new language or giving estimates on the cost of a renovation job.

For an organization, the suggestion of @Phil Sweet is the one to use:

***Moving up the learning curve***.  From [Wikipedia, Learning Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve):

A learning curve is a graphical representation of the increase of learning (vertical axis) with experience (horizontal axis).

> The term learning curve is used in two main ways: where the same task
>   is repeated in a series of trials, or where a body of knowledge is
>   learned over time.......In 1936, Theodore Paul Wright described the
>   effect of learning on production costs in the aircraft industry.[3]
>   This form, in which unit cost is plotted against total production, is
>   sometimes called an experience curve.
>
> The familiar expression "a steep learning curve" is intended to mean
>   that the activity is difficult to learn, although a learning curve
>   with a steep start actually represents rapid progress.

Another term, applicable to purely physical tasks, is ***muscle memory***.   [Wikipedia, Muscle Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory):

> Muscle memory has been used synonymously with motor learning, which is
>   a form of procedural memory that involves consolidating a specific
>   motor task into memory through repetition. When a movement is repeated
>   over time, a long-term muscle memory is created for that task,
>   eventually allowing it to be performed without conscious effort. This
>   process decreases the need for attention and creates maximum
>   efficiency within the motor and memory systems. Examples of muscle
>   memory are found in many everyday activities that become automatic and
>   improve with practice, such as riding a bicycle, typing on a keyboard,
>   typing in a PIN, playing a musical instrument,[1] martial arts or even
>   dancing.

Muscle memory is presumably the reason that practice makes perfect, but a recent [study reported by LiveScience](http://www.livescience.com/56218-muscles-have-no-strength-memory.html) says that muscle memory is misnamed.

> Although new results suggest that the muscle cells themselves do not
>   retain a "memory" from exercise, the same is not true for the nerves
>   that thread through the muscles, or the brain regions that control
>   movement.

Comment: So, the answer is perfection.

Comment: @user116032 Perfection is never attainable.  Practise just gets you closer to perfection.